# Attempted to assign to readonly property | React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to convert a React application that I built in React to React Native. I have an `onPress` event tied to a component that fetches data via Axios, `setState` with that data, then maps it to a component that handles the layout of the data, pretty simple. However, I'm getting the `Attempted to assign to readonly property` error and it's extremely vague, not sure where things are going wrong. Even if I could just get some insight on what this error stack even means would be helpful, thanks in advance! <3

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import NewSongLayout from "./NewSongLayout";
    export default class NewSongData extends Component {
      state = {
        songData: []
      };
      async componentWillMount() {
        try {
          const songList = await axios.get(
            "https://beatsaver.com/api/songs/new/{start?"
          );
          this.setState({
            songData: songList.data.songs
          });
          console.log(this.state.songData);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <>
            {this.state.songData.map(song => (
              <NewSongLayout key={song.id} song={song} />
            ))}
          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

[image: The error log]
The onPress event:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import NewSongData from "../Components/NewSongData";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%"
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: "Bangers",
    fontSize: 50,
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});

export default class Landing extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Beat Saber Companion</Text>
        <Button title="Newest Maps" onPress={NewSongData} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In your componentWillMount you don't assign the variable `songData` that you then use in your console.log. I think that line should be `console.log(this.state.songData);` You should paste your code in and not use an image of it.

Comment: Is the empty angle brackets just placeholder code or the actual code. Could you also share the onPress part of the code?

Comment: The empty brackets are React Native's equivalent to React Fragments, they are there unnecessarily

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html):

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

You should run the `axios` request from the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const songList = await axios.get(
        "https://beatsaver.com/api/songs/new/{start?"
      );
      this.setState({
        songData: songList.data.songs
      });
      console.log(this.state.songData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: After using constructor() when declaring state the error has changed to "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state = { songData: [] }')"

Answer (score 0):

I was using npm primarily in my project & accidentally executed a yarn command. By diving deep, I observed two lock files. Deleting yarn-lock.json did the trick for me.